# Integrating two identically distributed random variables.

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X,Y:(\Omega, \sigma) \longrightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \cal{\beta})$ random variables with the same distribution. It is known that $EX=EY$, i.e.,
$$\int_\Omega X dP=\int_\Omega Y dP$$ Does the equality holds if I change $\Omega$ for a set $D \in \sigma$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By no means it shall hold, since it only holds if $X = Y$ ($P$-a.s.) which is a much stronger constraint. The equality of distributions does not tell us anything about the interdependence of $X$ and $Y$, which is captured by their joint distribution $P$. You can still claim that
$$
  \int_\Omega g(X)\,\mathrm dP = \int_\Omega g(Y)\,\mathrm dP
$$
for any integrable $g$, but your condition will not be satisfied in general.

For a particular example, let $\Omega = \{0,1\}^2$, that is its element is e.g. $\omega = (0,1)$. Let $X$ be a projection on the first coordinate, $Y$ be a projection on the second. Let $P$ be a uniform distribution on $\Omega$ and $D = \{X = 0\}$, then 
$$
  \int_D X\,\mathrm dP = 0 \neq \frac14 = \int_D Y\,\mathrm dP = 1\cdot P(0,1).
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what if $D = \{\omega: X > c\} \cap \{\omega: Y < c\}$?

Comment: ... and it has non-zero probability.

Comment: Then $\int_D X-Y dP$ would be the integral of a positive random variable in a set with positive measure, so it would be also positive, and $\int_D X dP > \int_D Y dP$.